# Избыточность в конфигурации локализации

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, i18n

В [статье MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) по локализации ASP.Net Core приложения локализация настраивается и в `ConfigureService`, и в `Configure`, но выглядит оно как-то избыточно.

`ConfigureService`:

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("ru") };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportCultures[0]);

    options.SupportedCultures = supportCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportCultures;

    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
    {
        // My custom request culture logic
        return new ProviderCultureResult("en");
    }));
});
```

`Configure`:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    var supportCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("ru") };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportCultures[0]);

    options.SupportedCultures = supportCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportCultures;

    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
    {
        // My custom request culture logic
        return new ProviderCultureResult("en");
    }));
});
```

Нижняя часть полностью повторяет верхнюю.

Может я чего-то не понимаю и достаточно только один раз указать в любом из мест? И в чём разница где указывать, если так?

А если надо обязательно дублировать, то почему так?

Comment: Ну так вынесите лямбду в именованную функцию и не будет дублирования :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, в любом случае хотелось бы знать, действительно ли конфигурация требуется дважды и если да, то почему так? В Mircrosoft ведь не дураки сидят и просто так избыточность плодить не будут =/

Answer (score 0):

В `ConfigureServices` происходит настройка по-умолчанию.
В `Configure` происходит настройка для запроса, по сути переопределение настроек заданных в `ConfigureServices`.

Если вы настроите локализацию в `ConfigureServices`, то в `Configure` вам прилетят options такие, какие вы настроили ранее (можете поставить `breakpoint` в `Configure` и проверить, так как могу ошибаться). Это нужно если вы хотите переопределить локализацию для конкретного роута например.

Comment: то есть если меня устраивают конфиги в `ConfigureServices`, то в `Configure` я могу просто вызвать `app.UseRequestLocalization()` без аргументов?

Comment: По идее да, если там есть такая перегрузка